# How to restore the structure of the string after readLines()?

Tags: r, string, parsing, readline, backslash

I am working on a language parser to allow for translation (automated) and message selection based on a desired language.  So I am parsing my raw script files looking for a function named `prep.msg` and then I decompose the elements that need to be translated.

For example, let's say a file had the following code:

```
if( ( TYPE == "EXP" || TYPE == "POW") && any(df$y<=0) )
        {
        msg = prep.msg(
            "\n\n\t\t\t", 
            "For \"TRENDLINE\" type [",type,'] you can\'t have any data', 
            "\n\t\t\t\t",  
            "(currently [",n,"] rows) in [y] that is <= 0 (less than or equal to zero) ...", 
            "\n\t\t\t\t",  
            "the \\\"*SYSTEM*\\\" is REMOVING ROWS and trying to COMPUTE", 
            "\n\n");
```

You can verify that it is **valid** parsed code by creating a function:

```
prep.msg = function(...) { unlist(list(...)) }
```

You will note I have some edge cases: DQ (double quote) inside DQ, SQ (single quote) inside SQ, and some BACKSLASH elements around the `*SYSTEM*` element.

Here is what readLines does to the file content when I call the function:

```
 [1] ""                                                                                           
 [2] "if( ( TYPE == \"EXP\" || TYPE == \"POW\") && any(df$y<=0) )"                                
 [3] "\t\t{"                                                                                      
 [4] "\t\tmsg = prep.msg("                                                                        
 [5] "\t\t\t\"\\n\\n\\t\\t\\t\", "                                                                
 [6] "\t\t\t\"For \\\"TRENDLINE\\\" type [\",type,'] you can\\'t have any data', "                
 [7] "\t\t\t\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\",  "                                                               
 [8] "\t\t\t\"(currently [\",n,\"] rows) in [y] that is <= 0 (less than or equal to zero) ...\", "
 [9] "\t\t\t\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\",  "                                                               
[10] "\t\t\t\"the \\\\\\\"*SYSTEM*\\\\\\\" is REMOVING ROWS and trying to COMPUTE\", "            
[11] "\t\t\t\"\\n\\n\");"                                                                         
[12] "\t\t\t"
```

I have been able to recover the `\\n` and `\\t` with a simple string replace function (e.g., gsub fixed).

```
"\\n", "\n"
"\\t", "\t"
```

and the resulting output behaves **except** for the `*SYSTEM*` edge case:

```
> parse.lang(lines)
 
   idx line.no char.s char.e quote          what                                                       content
1    1       5     14     18    DQ     -.EMPTY.-                                                    \n\n\t\t\t
2    2       6     14     37    DQ -.TRANSLATE.-                                        For "TRENDLINE" type [
3    3       6     40     43    DQ    -.OBJECT.-                                                          type
4    4       6     46     71    SQ -.TRANSLATE.-                                     ] you can't have any data
5    5       7     14     18    DQ     -.EMPTY.-                                                    \n\t\t\t\t
6    6       8     14     25    DQ -.TRANSLATE.-                                                  (currently [
7    7       8     28     28    DQ    -.OBJECT.-                                                             n
8    8       8     31     90    DQ -.TRANSLATE.-  ] rows) in [y] that is <= 0 (less than or equal to zero) ...
9    9       9     14     18    DQ     -.EMPTY.-                                                    \n\t\t\t\t
10  10      10     14     72    DQ -.TRANSLATE.- the \\\\"*SYSTEM*\\\\" is REMOVING ROWS and trying to COMPUTE
11  11      11     14     15    DQ     -.EMPTY.-                                                          \n\n
```

That is, I can recognize a SQ or DQ is within a string.  I am trying to figure out how to get the BACKSLASH case to work.  If I use one of the BACKSLASH for the DQ in `*SYSTEM*`, it seems like the escaped DQ is being counted as a standard BACKSLASH.

I am trying to figure out a string replace technique before it enters the parser or a string replace technique after it enters the parser so the BACKSLASH count will work as expected.

### Question:  how to manipulate `lines` from `readLines` to account for the `*SYSTEM*` edgecase?

### Minimal Case

```
str = "the \\\"*SYSTEM*\\\" is REMOVING ROWS and trying to COMPUTE";

# lines = readLines("parse/parse-lang-simple.txt");
# line = lines[10];
# dput(line);

line = "            \"the \\\\\\\"*SYSTEM*\\\\\\\" is REMOVING ROWS and trying to COMPUTE\", ";
```

where `str` is from the RAW file (inside double quotes) and `line` is what readLines grabs (including the whitespace).

How to manipulate `line` so it is identical to `str`?

#### GOAL

```
nline = FUN(line);

identical(nline,str);
```

where `FUN` represents a function to manipulate the line.

Comment: You can use `parse("myfile")` and `deparse` to read in and parse code and to reverse it to strings.

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely something with the parser.  I have an odd/even problem right now with the number of BACKSLASH that I have.  If I were to use `readChar` from a binary scan of the file, would I get the same problem?